# How to get the Place Picker that compliant to the BLE technology(Eddystone)

Tags: android, google-places-api, eddystone

Google announced that the BLE technology will be introduced to Place Picker widget soon. It shows that the Place Picker detects own location by using Eddystone-UID signals. So now, I'm looking for the sample application of this But still not find out yet. If you have any information about it, please let me know.

So far my question is;
I guess Place Picker retrieves NAMESPACE ID and INSTANCE ID from the Eddystone-UID signals. How transfer this data to get the related PlaceID from the google's cloud.

And also if my understanding is wrong, please tell me correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to use [Google Play Services 7.8](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/08/google-play-services-78-lets-see-whats.html) client library, then the PlacePicker will by default center on any detected beacon that is registered with Google's Proximity Beacon API.  See [here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/place-picker) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Now, I have upgraded the library to Google Play Service 7.8 and downloaded the Place Picker repository from the Github. (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places) However, sample application did not recognize nearby beacon signals. Then, I checked code handling of this sample application. It looks there is no API for detecting BLE beacon. (I mean, no BLEscanner or something like that) So, if you have useful information, please let me know. (Sample code URL link is very helpful for me)